# what does "fetch_and_store" mean?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc

I am porting a linux c++ code into windows. But I cannot find replacement for the function fetch_and_store. 
here's the code:

```
size_t fn(size_t index)
{
    // do something here
    return fetch_and_store(array[index], size_t(0));
    // the type of array is size_t*
}
```

Actually, I am not familiar with gcc compiler．And this may be my first question in stackoverflow. If I did something wrong, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: why `C`?  [_note to  @CoryKramer: set a timer for 5 minute, I'm damn sure we'll get one more of this before the timer expires._]

Comment: @SouravGhosh The `size_t` tipped me off this time :) We'll see what the next post ends up being, so far its 1 C and 1 C++

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to tell us where that function came from (what library, header, etc) because it isn't part of the C++ standard library.

From the name alone, it sounds like an equivalent from the C++ Standard Library would be [`std::atomic::exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/exchange)

```
T exchange( T desired, std::memory_order order = std::memory_order_seq_cst );
```

> Atomically replaces the underlying value with desired. The operation is read-modify-write operation. Memory is affected according to the value of order.

Comment: *something out of the C++ standard ?

Comment: His version of `fetch_and_store` takes two parameters, so that's probably not that one.

Comment: @AdN I meant that `fetch_and_store` is not a function in the standard. Judging by the name, if it existed it would be in [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), but as I noted there is no such function, thought `exchange` sounds like a candidate.

Comment: @CoryKramer Okay, I did not know the idiom "nothing out of" could mean "not part of" (It seemed like double negation to me: it is nothing out <--> it is something in) ... English is tricky for us ; )

Comment: It might be a wrapper for compare_exchange or the older cas. Similar to `atomic_fetch_add()`.